# CSS 3 columns - First two fixed width, third remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns. `left`, `middle` and `right`.

`left` and `middle` are fixed-width, `right` should fill the remaining space.

How can I accomplish this?

Current HTML

```
<div id="menu">

    <div id="left">
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    </div>

</div>
```

LESS

```
#menu {

    width: 100%;

    #left {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }

    #middle {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
    }


    #right {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        float: right;
    }

}
```

Comment: Simply remove `float: right;` from `#right` element. `overflow-x: hidden;` does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/N7cu2/) with it all working.

It's "small-screen-first" so - if you aren't into that... then you can just delete the @media rule.

It looks like all you really need, is a width auto - and to make sure it's not floated.

### HTML

```
<aside class="container left"><h2>Left</h2></aside>

<section class="container main-content"><h2>Main content</h2></section>

<aside class="container right">
    <h2>Right</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et beatae quam quibusdam dolor dolorum vero harum commodi vel quidem quasi sed dolores iusto is</p>
</aside>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {

    .left {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .main-content {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .right {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    #left {
         width: 20%;
         float: left;
    }
    #middle {
         width: 300px;
         float: left;
    }
    #right {
         width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20% - 300px);
         width: -moz-calc(100% - 20% - 300px);
         width: -o-calc(100% - 20% - 300px);
         width: calc(100% - 20% - 300px);
         float: right;
    }
}
```

You must know that calc is still an experimental technology, I suggest you to use javascript instead if you are looking for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
#right{
     width:auto;
     float:right;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

has to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#middle {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* Show above #right */
}
#right {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: -300px; /* equal to width of #middle in px */
    padding-left: 300px; /* equal to width of #middle in px */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    float: right;
}
```